# Wired networking on Kubuntu 16.04 failed

Tags: networking, 16.04, kubuntu

Wired networking no longer works. It worked from install until now. I tried to reset the router and the homeplug AV (which is a wired network over power lines) - no change. homeplug still works with other systems. When I try to connect it, it reports

> ip configuration unavailable

The results of `lshw -C network` are:

```
warning: you should run this program as super-user.
description: ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor
physical ID:0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: enp3s0
version: 09
serial: 08:62:66:9e:1d:16
size: 1Gbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33 mhz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168f-1_0.0.5 06/18/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
resources: irq:34 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff
```

Running it `sudo` seems to add these capabilities:

> pm msi pciexpress msix vpd

Comment: May you please post the results of "lshw -C network" in your question?

Comment: it has been edited

Comment: Uhh..., may you run it as "sudo lshw -C network", and format your text with the brackets listed in the editor?